# XML - What values are allowed for the xml:base attribute?

Tags: xml, xhtml

I was wondering what values are allowed for the xml:base attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [XML Base](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/)

> The attribute `xml:base` may be inserted in XML documents to specify a base URI other than the base URI of the document or external entity. The value of this attribute is interpreted as a Legacy Extended IRI (LEIRI) as defined in the W3C Note "Legacy extended IRIs for XML resource identification"

See [Legacy extended IRIs for XML resource identification](http://www.w3.org/TR/leiri/) for technical details.

Here's an example from the spec:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc xml:base="http://example.org/today/"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <head>
    <title>Virtual Library</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <paragraph>See <link xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="new.xml">what's
      new</link>!</paragraph>
    <paragraph>Check out the hot picks of the day!</paragraph>
    <olist xml:base="/hotpicks/">
      <item>
        <link xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="pick1.xml">Hot Pick #1</link>
      </item>
      <item>
        <link xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="pick2.xml">Hot Pick #2</link>
      </item>
      <item>
        <link xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="pick3.xml">Hot Pick #3</link>
      </item>
    </olist>
  </body>
</doc>
```

**Edit**: IRI is an extension of URI, which is an extension of URL; so for the simple scenarios, you could think of them as URLs with lots of extensions.

[RFC3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987):

> A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is defined in [RFC3986] as a
> sequence of characters chosen from a limited subset of the repertoire
> of US-ASCII [ASCII] characters.
> This document defines a new protocol element called Internationalized
> Resource Identifier (IRI) by extending the syntax of URIs to a much
> wider repertoire of characters.

According to the spec,

> The syntax of Legacy Extended IRIs (LEIRIs) and LEIRI references is the same as that for IRIs and IRI references except that ucschar is redefined.

IRI:

```
ucschar        ::= %xA0-D7FF / %xF900-FDCF / %xFDF0-FFEF
                   / %x10000-1FFFD / %x20000-2FFFD / %x30000-3FFFD
                   / %x40000-4FFFD / %x50000-5FFFD / %x60000-6FFFD
                   / %x70000-7FFFD / %x80000-8FFFD / %x90000-9FFFD
                   / %xA0000-AFFFD / %xB0000-BFFFD / %xC0000-CFFFD
                   / %xD0000-DFFFD / %xE1000-EFFFD
```

LEIRI:

```
ucschar    ::=  " " / "<" / ">" / '"' / "{" / "}" / "|"
                    / "\" / "^" / "`" / %x0-1F / %x7F-D7FF
                    / %xE000-FFFD / %x10000-10FFFF
```

Comment: So exactly what are Legacy extended IRIs? Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: In plain term, they are URLs and relative paths that can potentially contain non-ASCII characters like chinese characters.